# root component gets removed in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

here i want to delete the node but as soon as i click the delete button
it delete the whole root component

here it it the header1 component

```
function Header1(){
    const [input,setInput]=useState({
        title:"",
        content:""
    })
    
    const [items,setItems]=useState([])

    function handleCheck(event){
       const {name,value}=event.target;
       setInput(prevValue=>{
       return {
        ...prevValue,
        [name]: value}    
       })
       }
       
       
       function addItem(){
        setItems( prevValue=>{
            return [...prevValue,input]
        }
        )
           setInput("")                                
       }

       function deleteItem(id){
       setItems(prevValue=>{
        prevValue.filter((item,index)=>{
            return index!==id
        })
       })
        }
       
return(<>

    <div className="h-1">
        <div className="i-1">
        <input onChange={handleCheck}  name="title" placeholder="title" value={input.title}/>
        <input onChange={handleCheck}  name="content" placeholder="description" value={input.content}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

      
       { items.map((item,value)=>{
        return <Note key={value} id={value} title={item.title} des={item.content}  del={deleteItem}  />
       })}
     
     
      
     
     </>
)
}

export default Header1;
```

here is the notes component ,here the adding is work but when the deleting part came
,it delete the main root component
when i click delte element i would like to delete the  component

```
function Note(props){
    function handleCheck(){
        props.del(props.id);
    }
return(
    <>
    <div className="note-container">
        <div className="container">
        <p className="note-title">{props.title}</p>
        <p className="note-content">{props.des}</p>
        <button onClick={handleCheck}
    >delete</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    </>
)

}


export default Note;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function...

```
function deleteItem(id){
  setItems(prevValue=>{
    prevValue.filter((item,index)=>{
      return index!==id
    })
  })
}
```

... doesn't do what you expect it does. Note that the callback function supplied as `setItems` param doesn't actually return anything: as `{}` are wrapping the function's body, it "expects" proper `return` statement. Without it, `undefined` is the result.

Here's one way to fix this:

```
function deleteItem(id){
  setItems(prevValue=>{
    return prevValue.filter((item,index)=>{
      return index!==id
    })
  })
}
```

... to be consistent. Alternatively, you can just drop the `{}` and use expressions directly:

```
function deleteItem(id){
  setItems(
    prevValue => prevValue.filter(
     (item,index) => index!==id
    )
  );
}
```

Without braces, result of expression put after `=>` is treated as this function's return value.